# Express - Use object received via the render function in an external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am passing an object from Express using the render function like so in my *index.js* file:

```
app.get("/chat", function(req, res){
  res.render("chat", {user: req.user});
});
```

I can use it in my *chat.ejs* file:

```
<% if(!user){ %>
  <li><a href="/auth/login">Connexion</a></li>
<% } else{ %>
  <li><a href="/profile">Profil</a></li>
  <li><a href="/chat">Chat</a></li>
  <li><a href="/auth/logout">Déconnexion</a></li>
<% } %>

<div id="output"></div>
```

A *chat.js* JavaScript file is linked to my *chat.ejs* file:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="/script/chat.js"></script>
```

However my external JavaScript doesn't know the user object when I want to output data inside the div tag:

```
typingFeedback.innerHTML = "<img src=" + user.thumbnail + "alt='Profile Image />";
let newP = document.createElement("p");
let newTxt = document.createTextNode(data.message);
newP.appendChild(newTxt);
output.appendChild(newP);
```

Here is a picture of how my files are organize: 
[image: My Files]

How can I use the user object in my external JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `chat.ejs` you could expose the user as a JavaScript object:

```
 <script>
  var user = <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>;
</script>
```

then you can access it as `user` from your code.

Comment: I added your piece of code in my "chat.ejs" file before the call of my "chat.js" script. Unfortunately, I still have the following error in my "chat.js" script : "Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined"

Comment: @titi157 did you take over the exact code? does the ejs insertion work as expected? Any other errors?